# How to use a variable to find a specific line in a file

Tags: unix, grep

I am using a variable("Address") that is read in from a file("finaladdress.txt"). The variable has info that I need to use to find a line from another file(cityfile.txt). The variable named "Address" as mentioned above contains the string "2320 Wisconsin NE, WA" I need to use that to grep the cityfile.txt. The grep part is the main problem. It tells me that Wisconsin: no such file exists, NE: no such file exists and so on. I hope I explained clearly enough here is the code snippet.

```
<code>
read Address < finaladdress.txt

grep $Address cityfile.txt 
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote your variable with double quotes:

```
 grep "$Address" cityfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want know only whether the row exists, you should enclose the variable because of the spaces.

```
grep "$Address" cityfile.txt
```